# Encountering an error while appending text in Excel comment - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code that I am trying to append new text to an existing comment. However, when I execute, it is spitting an error - "Application defined/Object defined error". Could someone help?

```
For Each c In Range("G" & iCellIndex)
  If StrComp(JSONObj2("fields")("worklog")("worklogs")(j + 1)("author")("displayName"), Range("G" & iCellIndex).Value) = 0 Then
     Set cmt = ActiveCell.AddComment
     cmt.Comment.Text iTimeStamp & "--" & JSONObj2("fields")("worklog")("worklogs")(j + 1)("timeSpent") , 1, False
     Range("G" & iCellIndex).AddComment iTimeStamp & "--" & JSONObj2("fields")("worklog")("worklogs")(j + 1)("timeSpent") , 1, False
  End If
  iCellIndex = iCellIndex + 1
Next c
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: This one ----   cmt.Comment.Text iTimeStamp & "--" & JSONObj2("fields")("worklog")("worklogs")(j + 1)("timeSpent") , 1, False

Comment: Oh, that "cv" is a copy error when I did a "Ctrl + v" :) Fixed it!

Comment: Try separating out the line that throws the error into multiple lines to see which part is causing the problem

Comment: I get it that some people do not wish to "hand" the code/answer in an attempt to encourage self learning. But, with all due respect, there could be situations where the questioner is out of time and wits and that is why they turn to forums like this. I did try to the best of my knowledge to fix the error and my brain ran out of ideas. So, I'd appreciate if you could be a little bit more specific than the enigmatic "separate out", that is, of course, if you wish to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, this is how I fixed the issue:

```
If StrComp(JSONObj2("fields")("worklog")("worklogs")(j + 1)("author")("displayName"), Range("G" & iCellIndex).Value) = 0 Then
   Range("G" & iCellIndex).NoteText Text:=Range("G" & iCellIndex).NoteText & Chr(10) & iTimeStamp & "   --   " & JSONObj2("fields")("worklog")("worklogs")(j + 1)("timeSpent") & Chr(10)
End If
```